# How to escape double quotes in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, escaping

I have tried / to escape the double quotes in a string but i am not able to get the desired string.

The code snippets are as follows in Node.js

```
var queryString = "select * from courier where couriername LIKE '%"+filterName+"%'";
console.log(querystring);
```

The output i am getting is like with double quotes included on console:

```
select * from courier where couriername LIKE '%"a"%'
```

But I want output like this

```
 select * from courier where couriername LIKE '%a%';
```

How to get this .. I have tried many things ...

Comment: Can't you use parameterised queries instead?

Comment: Never create SQL queries in JavaScript. A user of your website can easily modify these to do anything they want in your database (this is called an SQL injection). Send "filterName" to the server, and process it there using prepared statements.

Comment: I think the double quotes comes from your filterName variable.

Comment: This code is in Node.js file which is server-side. Hence my code is running on server-side only.. the message is getting printed on server-side console

Comment: @Baart I am storing filter in variable filtername .. the quotes are being put by me to get the filtername from query string.

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(filterName);`?

Comment: @mvuajua the ouput is just a

Comment: you're logging querystring instead of queryString, typo or might that be the problem?

Comment: Sorry guys ... I made a silly mistake ... the variable filter is returning with doublequotes... it is returning "a" instead it should be a. Thanx a lot for your replies

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that filterName is equal to "a" and not a

Can you log its value ?